# Loading WebView with cache

Tags: android, caching, android-webview

MainWeb.class:

```
webb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.nonMain);
    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webb.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    webb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webTimer = new Timer();
    webTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reloadSite();
        }

    }, 0, 1000*60*2); // once 2 hours
```

reloadSite():

```
public void reloadSite() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
                webb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                System.out.println("OFFLINE");
            } else {
                webb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default
                System.out.println("ONLINE");
            }

            webb.loadUrl("http://screens.company/manage/showadv.php?bid=" + ID);
            System.out.println("WEBSITE RELOADED.");
        }
    });
}
```

I'm reloading my website every two minutes, and I wanted that if I have no internet connection it will show the cache of the website so it'll keep running even without network connection but without updating. but still, if I have no network connection, I get "Can't find website CONNECTION REFUSED".

EDIT:

isNetworksAvailable():

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: is the seize of your cache perhaps too small? Try setting `webb.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 );`

Comment: Still no luck...